# conversion to static_cast<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, c++11

Does a conversion like:

```
int a[3];
char i=1;
a[ static_cast<unsigned char>(i) ];
```

introduce any overhead like conversions or can the compiler optimize everything away?
I am interested because I want to get rid of `-Wchar-subscripts` warnings, but want to use a char as index (other reasons)

Comment: Given the posting verbatim, as `a[ static_cast<unsigned char>(i) ];`is an utterly unused expression, I have confidence any remotely intelligent optimizer will throw out the entire thing,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did one test on Clang 3.4.1 for this code :

```
int ival(signed char c) {
    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    unsigned char u = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
    return a[u];
}
```

Here is the relevant part or the assembly file generated with `c++ -S -O3`

```
_Z4ivala:                               # @_Z4ivala
# BB#0:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movzbl  8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    .L_ZZ4ivalaE1a(,%eax,4), %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

There is no trace of the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

On most modern architectures `char` and `unsigned char` have the same size and alignment, hence `unsigned char` can represent all non-negative values of `char` and casting one to another does not require any CPU instructions.